# htaccess redirect with variable added to end

Tags: .htaccess

So, I can't quite figure out the redirect for this. I'm moving a subdomain and all of its content to another domain, but want to add a variable to the end of every url so that it ends up like so:

```
http://old.domain.com/products/something-or-other.html
```

turns into

```
http://www.newdomain.com/products/some-or-other.html?p=abc
```

I tried this but it doesn't add the variable unless you're only on the root of the domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://new.domain.com/$1/p_ig=abc [R=301,L]
```

EDIT (figured it out with a RedirectMatch instead):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/(.*)$ http://new.domain.com/$1/$2?p_ig=abc
```

Comment: Apache will look for the lowest folder with a .htaccess in it, so is there a `products` folder and does it have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.domain.com${REQUEST_URI}?p_ig=abc [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Once you verify that it's working fine then change `R=302` to `R=301`.